# Multiple SqlCommand sharing variables

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have two SqlCommand that look like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into table1...etc; declare @id as int = @@identity;");
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into table2 (ParentID) values(@id);");
```

Is there a way to use the @id variable, created in cmd1, in cmd2?

The commands are run sequentially inside the same connection and transaction.

Comment: Maybe you should create a stored-procedure that you call.

Comment: If all three statements were in one `SqlCommand` it wouldn't be a problem. You could `select @id;` and capture the output from `cmd1` and then use it as a parameter in `cmd2`. Or just use `@@Identity` in `cmd2`. The value will still be there if you only perform the `insert` in `cmd1`. And you might want to change to [`Scope_Identity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) since it returns the expected result regardless of triggers.

Comment: Thank you comments, I am aware of both suggestions, but in my case cmd2 can contain anything, including insert statements. I could not find a way to make it work so I changed the code to use a single TSQL statement, but it's not as flexible as I wanted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possibilities:

1 - Use SqlParameters.
Before executing cmd1, add an output parameter:

```
    SqlParameter p1 = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
    p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

In sql of cmd1, change:

```
 declare @id as int = @@identity;
```

to:

```
 set @id = @@identity
```

After executing cmd1, fetch value of @id, and pass it to cmd2:

```
    object idValue = p1.Value;

    SqlParameter p2 = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
    p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    p2.Value = idValue;
```

The sql of cmd2 will be able to access @id, just as your example sql shows.

OR

2 - Use sesssion context.
e.g.
At the end of the sql for cmd1, do something like:

```
-- save @id to session_context
EXEC sp_set_session_context @key='id', @value = @id
```

At the start of the sql for cmd2, do something like:

```
-- restore @id from session_context
declare @id int = cast(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'id') as int)
```

Comment: Great solutions! I will go with the output parameter.